# Filter DataFrame by missing Pairs

Tags: python, pandas

There are two datasets: `cells` and `connections`. Every `cell` has an `id` and every `connection` is defined by two ids `(id1,id2)`.

There is a maximum of `count(cells)^2` different connections.

I want to have a subset `cells_subset` with the condition, that every pair of cells from `cells_subset` has an connection in `connections`.

Who can I do it with pandas?

Answer (score 0):

```
cells_subset = cells[(cells.id.isin(list(connections.id1)))|
                     (cells.id.isin(list(connections.id2)))].copy()
```

Just two propositions, with an OR statement: id is in either id1 or id2.

Comment: Hi. There is a missing ) at two positions. I can't edit your answer.

Comment: @sreved fixed! Thanks for spotting it :p